# creating a invoice (php)

Tags: php, javascript

i'm creating ERP system  to work with my pharmacy.
in the billing form of that system i want to add items and print a bill.
i have a little problem, where could i hold my 1st items information while i'm adding a second item to it.. 
my billing form is like this ( only a dummy)

```
<table width="490" height="282" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="206">Date</td>
      <td width="160">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="47">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="69">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bill Number</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Code</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Expier Date</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Price</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Each</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="adnother" id="adnother" value="add another item" tabindex="5" /></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

while adding items to this form one by one, i want those items to be shown in a separate window on the same page (printable version of the bill)  any way i can do it. the big problem i have is the thing that i said earlier. {sorry for my bad english :P }

Comment: Separate window on the same page? Whay do you mean exactly?

Comment: i mean using a iframe. or what ever i can do it. my biggest problem is how to add items one after one and finally put them all together. do i need to use arrays or a table to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store in a session, or in a database, or any other mechanism PHP offers to persist data between requests. See PHP manual for sessions.

Regarding window - you can simply have one page, show the table, and have the form open in other browser window, using JavaScript's  `window.open(...)` method.

You will probably want to refresh the bill window when the adding window is submitted - see `window.onclose()` and `window.refresh()`

Comment: sir, if i use sessions can i add items one after one and print all items in a one bill? i just know how to add one item to a session but how can i add the second item?

Comment: Sure, just store an `Array()` in the session, and add to the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

How about managing the invoices in the `DataBase` as you build it up?

This way you could review all past invoices. It would also allow you to save incomplete invoices for later if that is a need.

Comment: sir, i also think the easiest way to do this is feed those data into table and print. but sir if this happened recently will it take more space in my server?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is similar to shopping cart problem and Most php systems manage it by storing it in sessions with an option to save it in database.

Comment: sir, if i use sessions can i add items one after one and print all items in a one bill? i just know how to add one item to a session but how can i add the second item?

Comment: you can store an array in session instead of storing a simple variable

Comment: yes sir i got it. now i'm using multidimensional array. think it will do my work.

Answer (score 0):

i think best way to do this is using multidimensional arrays to create session. now i'm working on it.  will see.. 
 thank you all for your valuable comments HATS OFF to u guys